# StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header:

Tags: java, json, rest, httpwebrequest, jersey

I am getting a StreamCorruptedException and I have no idea why or how it's happening.
Any help would be awesome! 
Here is the Client:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
Map params = new HashMap<String, Object>();     
Order[] orders = odao.getOpenOrdersByTenant(tenantID);

JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
jObj.put("params", params);
jObj.put("sourcePath", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/reports/OpenOrders.jasper");
jObj.put("method", "html");
jObj.put("datasource", orders);

ClientResponse response =       service.path("rest").path("jasper").path("getJasperReport").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class,jObj);
```

Server:

```
@POST
@Path("/getJasperReport")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void getJasperReport(@Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest, @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse, @Context UriInfo uriInfo )
                throws ServletException, IOException{

ObjectInputStream objInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(servletRequest.getInputStream());
JSONObject jobj =  (JSONObject) objInputStream.readObject();
```

The Second to last line throws a java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7B227061

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectInputStream is for reading java serialized data, not JSON formatted data.

You probably want something like `new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(servletRequest.getReader()))`.

Comment: So how do I abstract my request entity? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Still having problems with it. I am now getting a Illegal State Exception telling me that GetInputStream has already been called.

Comment: @Garvice - what does your current code look like?  did you remove your previous call to getInputStream?

Comment: That's the problem. There isn't any previous call to getInputStream... The first call that is made at all is getReader()